# c++: access derived class method when passing a pointer to the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

I apologize for the nooby question, but I've just started programming in obj-oriented paradigm.

I have a function that takes a pointer to a class `void foo(myClass* C)` and this class has its own method

```
      class myClass{
      public:
          double fooMethod();
          /* ... */
      }
```

Now I would like to pass to `foo` an object with an overloaded method `fooMethod` so I thought about creating a derived class

```
      class myDerivedClass : public myClass{
      public:
          double fooMethod(); // overloaded method
          /* ... */
      }
```

The problem is that if I instantiate an object `myDerivedClass* D = new myDerivedClass` and pass it `foo(D)`, this function will use the method of the base class, i.e., `myClass::fooMethod()` and instead I would like it to use `myDerivedClass::fooMethod()`.

How do I make this happen? I have this problem since I don't want to re-write already working code, like `foo` or `myClass`, but I would like to adapt my new features to the current structure of the code.

Thank you very much!
L.

Comment: you must declare your method virtual.

Comment: @Kiroxas do you mean in the base class or in the derived class? Or both?

Comment: in the base class, the derived class will inherit it by default, but you can add it there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
class myClass{
  public:
      virtual double fooMethod();
      /* ... */
  }

class myDerivedClass : public myClass{
  public:
      double fooMethod() override; // override  method, not overload
      /* ... */
  }
```

Then if you pass a `myDerivedClass` object pointer/reference, and use it to call `fooMethod()`, the `overriden` method in `myDerivedClass` will be called.

The concept is you can [**override**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) base class method, not [**overload**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

Comment: Thank you! That was explanatory! @Barmaley.exe

Answer (score 1):

In object-oriented programming in order to derived class' method be executed when you call base class' method you need that method to be `virtual`. In some languages like Java all methods by default are virtual, but in C++ you have to manually add keyword `virtual` in method definition in base class, like this:

```
class myClass{
public:
    virtual double fooMethod();
    /* ... */
}
```